# How to update an element reference with jQuery Cloneya

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-cloneya

In the code below, how do I get [jQuery cloneya](https://github.com/yapapaya/jquery-cloneya) to update the 'uploader1' reference so that it reads 'uploader2' in the second clone, 'uploader3' in the third clone and so on?
The "file1" field updates fine as you would expect, "file2", "file3" etc.

```
<div id="clone-fields">
 <div class="toclone clone-widget">
  <div class="spacer-b10">
   <label class="field file prepend-icon">

    <span class="button"> Choose File </span>
    <input type="file" class="gui-file" name="attach[]" id="file1" onChange="document.getElementById('uploader1').value = this.value;">
    <input type="text" class="gui-input" id="uploader1" placeholder="Add images relevant to this event" readonly>
    <span class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></span>

   </label>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="clone button btn-blue"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="delete button"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: would use a jquery event delegation change handler for this instead of using `onChange`. Show more of html structure and what will be cloned

Comment: I tried to use  this.element.nextSibbling in place of document.getElementById('uploaded1'), but it didn't seem to work. I would have thought both 'inputs' were siblings?

Comment: How about using [before_clone](https://github.com/yapapaya/jquery-cloneya/wiki/Events#before_clone) event to modify the reference. Use regular expression on toClone param to change it.

Comment: before_clone sounds good but why did the '.nextSibbling' not work? It would be a nice clean solution if it did.